# Shared Workers - can I have different sets of the same shared worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, shared-worker

I have implemented a sharedWorker as a communication channel between multiple tabs in my web application.

However, I don't want a sharedWorker in one tab communicating with a sharedWorker in another tab if a different user is logged in on each tab.

Is there some option I can pass into the sharedWorker constructor to achieve this separation?

```
var myWorker = new SharedWorker(aURL, options);
```

For example: an **identifier** property inside options.

I understand that I can probably handle this inside my worker script, but the documentation on sharedWorkers isn't too detailed, and I would rather not implement something that is already baked in.

Thanks!

Comment: you can pass a name in the options argument, and check that in the worker before proceeding to work. the name is not required or specified, so it should be free to use as-needed.

Comment: Just copy your script or serve it by another name and create another shared worker instance?